# MySQL exact word existence check in a table Field

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I've a Query. Is there any built-in function or any other method associated with MySQL, which will return rows that contains EXACT word in the database table field? I'm aware that with MySQL LIKE operator, You can search for a specified pattern in a column which will match a string value against a pattern string containing wild-card characters. But With MySQL LIKE clause, It'll return substring entries too.

Eg.

Suppose 3 column values are like below:

```
1. "Take another shot of courage"

2. "The End of This age is Not Yet"

3. "Employers can obtain this wage rate by submitting a request"
```

I want to retrieve all rows in which column value contains the exact word 'age'

If we prepare query like this

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE '%age%'
```

It'll return all three rows. But my intention is only to get the second row. How do we achieve this? Thanks In Advance.

Cheers,
**JENSon.**

Comment: If there will always be a space before and after age, why not use LIKE ' %age% '

Comment: Place two space before and after age and see if works. I mean `% age %`

Comment: read about full text search, `% age %` isn't solution for me.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE '% age %' will work for most cases except for "age something" and "something age"

Comment: @fizzy drink: i didnt see you already given the same idea. Sorry for duplication. But theorit!cally it should work. Thanks

Comment: @JensonMJohn Accept the answer which has solved your problem...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE '% age %' 
OR somefield LIKE 'age %' OR somefield LIKE '% age'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use MySQL's regex engine and match the word boundary characters `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

This will match `age` but not `courage` or `wage` or `aged`. It will also match the age in `-age-` or any other row where the text `age` is surrounded by **non word** characters. This means it will match `age` at the beginning and end of the string.

It is a little less complicated to read in my opinion than having three conditions. If returning matches like `-age-` is acceptable then you might consider this.

I have not tested the performance or portability of this query either so you might want to consider that as well.

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield RLIKE '[[:<:]]age[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  1 SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE '% age %' to search in middle of string

2 SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE '% age' if word is at end of string

3 SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield LIKE 'age %' if your word is at starting of the string
```