# Django MySQL Exact Word Match With iRegex Search

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django

I am trying to get a column that has an exact word say **yax** and not **yaxx** but I keep getting the two for whichever one that search for. I want only **yax** when I search for **yax** regardless of case.

I have tried:

```
key = 'yax'
query = Model.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"[[:<:]]*{0}*[[:>:]]".format(key))
```

Answers I have checked but didn't quite help me:

1. [This...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599956/3009875)
2. [And this...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004968/3009875)
3. [And this too...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831933/3009875)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that's it! It's working! Muchas gratias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` from your regex.

```
query = Model.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"[[:<:]]{0}[[:>:]]".format(key))
```